# How to restart unity animator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

I used an animator to count down (three seconds using the finger model). I succeeded in making a countdown animator. I want to play the animator whenever I want because this project requires countdowns several times for calibration.

But I do not know how. Now I can not play the animator when I want, nor do I know how to play it again. Currently, the animator is created in the animator window, not as a script.

[image]

Comment: Check the [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html) Documantation and see how to play/stop the animation.

Comment: Once the scene is played, the animator will play once, but I want to know how to play that animator whenever I need to.

Comment: I know how to play continuously through the loop function, but I want to run a 3 second animator every 3 seconds reading the value from the sensor!

Answer (score 2):

```
animator.Play("animation name", layer, normalizedTime);
```

This is the overload.
More precisely do this:

```
animator.Play("your animation name", -1, 0f);
```

If you want, you can use co-routine as well. It's my preferred way:

```
private IEnumerator Counter(int secondsToCount)
{
    while (secondsToCount >= 0)
    {
        //'counter' is the counter that appears to the player
        counter.text = secondsToCount.ToString();
        secondsToCount--;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}
```

This way you have control how many seconds you want to count down.

EDIT:

If you are new and know nothing of co-routines. You can start them like this:

```
StartCoroutine(Counter(5));
```

This will count from 5 to 0.